# Minimum value javascript in result

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm working on a smart pdf with easy javascript fields.

But i've got an issue with one on them :

```js
var a = this.getField("caution").value;
var b = 0;

if (a < "3000")
    {event.value = a * 0.08 ;}

else
    {event.value = b ;}
```

I would like to add a minimal value of 75. For example, if a = 500 the result is 40 and I want 75 instead. It seems easy but i cant handle with it.

Any help ?

Thanks,

Loïc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this,

```
var a = this.getField("caution").value;
var b = 0;

if (a < "3000")
    {event.value = a * 0.08 ;
     if(event.value < "75")
      {event.value = 75;}
    }

else
    {event.value = b ;}
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, your solution is almost perfect but in this way I have a default value of 75, even if the "caution" value is 0. I woud like to have "75" if the value is more than 0, and then if the value is more than "75", the result of 0.08 * "caution". Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Try adding and AND check to your if statement

if(event.value > "0" && event.value < "75")

Comment: Perfect in this way ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could add another check.

```
var a = +this.getField("caution").value;
var b = 0;

if (event.value < 75 / 0.08) { // event.value < 937.5
    event.value = 75;
else if (a < 3000) {
    event.value = a * 0.08;
} else {
    event.value = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified to:

```
var a = this.getField("caution").value;
var b = 0;

if (a < "3000" && a > 0) {
event.value = Math.max(a * 0.08, 75) ;
} else {
event.value = b ;
}
```

An that does it.

Note: edit: added a condition for a <= 0, where event value is to be 0.

Comment: Hi Max, your solution is almost perfect but in this way I have a default value of 75, even if the "caution" value is 0. I woud like to have "75" if the value is more than 0, and then if the value is more than "75", the result of 0.08 * "caution". Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I have updated the code by adding "a > 0" as second condition.